# I'm not able to change HTML in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change HTML code in jQuery, currently my HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="intro-lead-in"><span>Creating quality Foods, Since 1940</span></div>
```

Expecting HTML code like below using jQuery:

```
<div class="intro-lead-in"><span>Creating quality Foods,<span class="class-name">Since 1940</span></span></div>
```

How can I accomplish this using jQuery?

Comment: `document.querySelector(".intro-lead-in").innerHTML = document.querySelector(".intro-lead-in").innerHTML.replace("Since 1950", "<span>Since 1950</span>")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JonasWilms : working as expected (Y)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how do you determine what class names to put and where to split `span`s, but I'm assuming you wanna do it on commas.

Assuming a container of class `intro-lead-in`:
First, setup what classes do you want for each text fragment. I'm supposing from your exemple:

```js
fragmentClassBindings = ['', 'class-name']
```

Then, do the actual replacing...

```js
fragments = $('.intro-lead-in').html().split(',')
fragments.forEach(fragment => {
   full = $('.into-lead-in').html()
   cls = fragmentClassBindings[fragments.indexOf(fragment)]
   $('.intro-lead-in').html(full.replace(fragment, `<span class="${cls}">${fragment}</span>`))
})
```

However, too much things are assumed here, you really need more explanation in your question. What are you trying to accomplish? What logic leads to the exemple you've provided?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Mx3 : 

two span's i have to display, child span required class name

<div class="intro-lead-in"><span>Creating quality Foods,<span class="class-name">Since 1940</span></span></div>